# Bug in siunitx?

Tags: siunitx, bugs

I am using power to 1/2 in `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[per-mode = symbol-or-fraction]{siunitx}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\begin{document}

\unit{\second\tothe{\text{\sfrac12}}}

\unit{\meter\per\second\tothe{\text{\sfrac12}}}

\end{document}
```

It works fine when `\per` is not used.  However, with `\per` I get strange errors:

```
<argument> \???  
                 ! LaTeX Error: Erroneous variable \protect used!
l.XX ...{\meter\per\second\tothe{\text{\sfrac12}}}
```

It seems that there is some bug in `siunitx`.  Anyone has any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: seems to work if you replace the `\tothe` with the `^` carrot. Might be a bug, or might just be that the m/s construction doesn't like the exponent for whatever reason.

Comment: @Jake Yes, but this workaround does not work if you use something like `\DeclareSIPostPower\rooted{\text{\sfrac{1}{2}}}` and then `\rooted`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `\tothe{\sfrac{1}{2}}` you are relying on `siunitx` printing the power with no mathematical intervention: the unit is handled in 'parsed' mode as everything 'looks' parsable (there are no out-and-out literals). However, once you add `\per`, in parsed mode `siunitx` needs to do maths with the exponent. That fails as `\sfrac{1}{2}` is not a number.

What you should be doing here is helping out `siunitx` using `parse-units = false`: that forces literal printing, and no inversion of the fraction is attempted.

---

I will think a bit about whether this should *always* be an error. I have in the past toyed with conversion of fractions in exponents, but it looks quite a lot of code and not 100% reliable. I will though look at this again: I'll log some issues.

Comment: https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/682 and https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/683

Comment: To be clear, an easy 'fix' for me is to always evaluate the input, then you'd always get an error - consistent but likely not what's wanted. So I'll treat as a feature request and sort that before making a change.

Comment: As it is, it just works to my needs.  `\unit{\W\s\rooted\per\m\squared\per\K}` is the unit for effusion and `\unit[parse-units = false]{\m\per\s\rooted}` for sorptivity.  Both in `per-mode = symbol-or-fraction`.